# object has no attribute 'writerow' appending to file python

Tags: python

I am able to write the headers to a csv file using python with these lines in my script:

```
with open(output_file, mode='w+') as csv_file:
    csv_file = open(output_file, mode='w+')
    title_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    title_writer.writerow(["AWS Instance List " + today])
    fieldnames = ['Name', 'Instance ID', 'Type', 'State', 'Private IP', 'Public IP', 'Region', 'Availability Zone', 'Launch Time', 'AWS Account', 'Account Number']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writeheader()
```

But when I go to append to that file later on in the script in line 139:

```
with open(output_file,'a') as fd:
    fd.writerow({'Name': name, 'Instance ID': instance["InstanceId"], 'Type': instance["InstanceType"], 'State': instance["State"]["Name"], 'Private IP': private_ips_list, 'Public IP': public_ips_list, 'Region': region['RegionName'], 'Availability Zone': instance['Placement']['AvailabilityZone'], 'Launch Time': launch_time_friendly, 'AWS Account': aws_account, "Account Number": aws_account_number})
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 254, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 247, in main
    loop_regions(aws_account,aws_account_number)
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 139, in loop_regions
    fd.writerow({'Name': name, 'Instance ID': instance["InstanceId"], 'Type': instance["InstanceType"], 'State': instance["State"]["Name"], 'Private IP': private_ips_list, 'Public IP': public_ips_list, 'Region': region['RegionName'], 'Availability Zone': instance['Placement']['AvailabilityZone'], 'Launch Time': launch_time_friendly, 'AWS Account': aws_account, "Account Number": aws_account_number})
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writerow'
```

The error is on line 139. The other two line numbers are just function calls.

Why is this happening? How can I append to this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a plain file object

You need to create a CSV writer again via `writer = csv.DictWriter(fd,...)` like you did before

Then you can use write row function again

Alternatively, pre-collect all the data you need before opening the file, then use the same writer object (and open file) you already have

In pseudocode

```
# get data 
# open file 
    # open writer 
    # write headers 
    # for each row in data 
        # write data row
```

---

Note: you're opening the same file twice here. You should remove the second line

```
with open(output_file, mode='w+') as csv_file:
    csv_file = open(output_file, mode='w+')
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I've removed the second line. Now I am trying to use the same write I declared before. But why am I getting this error now.

Comment: Well, `instance["InstanceId"]` doesn't exist. Nothing in my answer would fix/affect that

Comment: whoops! Sorry I didn't present that part of the code. Here's my program if you don't mind taking a look! https://pastebin.com/x5a1gpVU

Comment: Note that if I remove this line the program works as intended, except that of course it doesn't write to the file: `row_writer.writerow(...`

Comment: I'm not sure what data is in your dictionary, so I'm not sure how I can help

Comment: I've actually resolved the issue, but I did have to reopen the file for 'append'. The script works great now! If you're at all curious you can check it out here: https://pastebin.com/MRJaAZ40

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a file object, and then pass it to `csv.writer`, you have repeated the statement `csv_file = open(output_file, mode='w+')`, which you do not need to.

```
with open(output_file, mode='w+') as csv_file:
    #You already did it, no need to repeat this statement
    #csv_file = open(output_file, mode='w+')
    title_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    title_writer.writerow(["AWS Instance List " + today])
    fieldnames = ['Name', 'Instance ID', 'Type', 'State', 'Private IP', 'Public IP', 'Region', 'Availability Zone', 'Launch Time', 'AWS Account', 'Account Number']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writeheader()
```